# What is heat of vaporization? How can it be used at temperature as low as 25 °C?

Tags: enthalpy

When I first learned this term. I was introduced to this graph: [image]

The heat in this case is at 100 °C, which I had ever since believed to be the only temperature of vaporization, **assuming vaporization = boiling.**

Then I saw a table with all the heat of vaporization values for different compounds. Most importantly, all these values apply to reactions at 25  °C.

Different heat of vaporization values apply to different temperature. **but water, for ex., cannot boil, with vapor bubbles, unless at 100 °C, thus all the energy used will just be used to simply raise the temperature.** *wouldn't it?*

Comment: How can water boil being supplied the heat of vaporization at 25C?

Comment: But is it even necessary to make water boil to convert from liquid to gas? I mean since evaporation is constantly happening, isn't this heat of vaporization just making evaporation go faster?

Answer (score 4):

Think of vaporization as the removal of the fastest molecules. The separation of the gaseous form from the more closely-bound liquid therefore removes energy from the liquid. The heat of vaporization can apply at much lower temperatures than the BP of water *at atmospheric pressure*. Even on a day when the temperature is well blow freezing, laundry will dry on a clothesline because ice evaporates (well, sublimes). Also, water at skin temperature soon feels cold as it loses heat through evaporation.

BTW, the boiling point of water is 100 °C only at 1 atmosphere; see this [video of water boiling at room temperature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOYgdQp4euc), ~25 °C.

Comment: So if I am given a table of heat of vaporization on test, let's say, according what you say, I am then also given the pressure?

Comment: No, a liquid can evaporate much below its boiling point.

Comment: When water evaporates from a cup is the temperature of the vapor equal to the temperature of liquid water in the cup?

Comment: Since the vapor is made of the fastest-moving molecules, which escaped attractive forces in the liquid, which do you think would be warmer?